# Allocate memory dynamically for socket programming

Tags: c++

I have a callback that is triggered whenever a specific event happens (recvmsg in BSD socket). This callback needs a buffer to be passed so I can get the received data. Both ways below work but the second method needs memory management which I try to avoid. Is the first way OK? It works in unix based OS but it didn't compile in Windows as it requires `new`, any idea how the first way can be used in Windows?

(1)

```
unsigned char buffer[1024]; // no need to delete
receivePacket(void *buffer){
   // some socket codes to define msg and assing the buffer (removed here for simpicity)
   recvmsg(socketFD, &msg, MSG_DONTWAIT);
}
// at this point the buffer contains the received data
```

(2)

```
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[1024];   // need data delete []
receivePacket(void *buffer){
   // some socket codes to define msg and assing the buffer (removed here for simpicity)
   recvmsg(socketFD, &msg, MSG_DONTWAIT);
}
// at this point the buffer contains the received data
```

Comment: You can give size to an array dynamically (method "1" in your codes) if you are using Dev-Cpp compiler but on visual c++ and visual studio compilers it is not possible.

Comment: " but it didn't compile in Windows as it requires new" what does that mean? `new` can be used also in Windows

Comment: The real mystery is why you're not punting around a `std::vector<uint8_t>` for this in the first place.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I don' want to use `new` as this would required `delete []` which I would avoid

Comment: if you have problem with code that does not compile, please include a [mcve] and the compiler error in the question

Answer (score 1):

> Is the first way OK?

Sure.

> It works in unix based OS but it didn't compile in Windows as it requires new, any idea how the first way can be used in Windows?

`new` isn't a unix feature. Both ways can be used on any standard conforming (hosted) system including Windows.

Comment: first way does not compile in Windows?